# How to see questions asked by me that were closed or maybe on hold?

Tags: support

How to see questions asked by me that were closed or maybe on hold?

Comment: I didn't see that you were talking about questions that you had asked, rather than answered. Well I don't know, why did you feel the need to add "Reasons obvious" at the end of your post? Just be aware that on average only 3-4 questions get reopened each day, and they see substantial improvements in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for "user:me closed:yes" will yield your (undeleted) closed questions.

To find deleted ones is more tricky, see [this recent answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19766/)  for instructions.

Comment: for deleted one go to questions then there's a small text at the corner left "see deleted..."